# Web Service to use for SQL database access from an android device

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

So, I was originally going to use JDBC to connect an android app to a MySQL database, but I read that this was a bad idea and was difficult to make work. So apparently, I need to use a web server to access the database indirectly. Is there any way I can get this to work without paying out any money in hosting a server?

Also, are there any resources I can be directed to for this specific question to be answered more in depth? I'm having a hard time finding where to start

Comment: It sounds like you're connecting to a *remote* MySQL database from Android. Could you host a web server on the same remote machine? Can you be more specific about the requirements for your work?